# Finding the selected <option> in a <select> using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to know when someone clicks on a specific select option.  It's for a search form and I want users to have the ability search between dates, so if they select the option to search between dates then it will show the second date search field. I am using the bootstrap datepicker for the date inputs

Here's an example of my HTML:

```
<select name="select_menu" id="select_field">
    <option value="select_one">Please Select One</option>
    <option value="search_between_dates">Search Between Two Dates</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="date" id="dpd1" class="dpd1">
<div id="select_feed"></div>
```

Example PHP for it:

```
if(isset($_GET['filter'])) {
    $filter = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['filter']);
    if($filter == 'search_between_dates') {
        $date1 = $_GET['date'];
        $date2 = $_GET['date2'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN '".$date1."' AND '".$date2."';
        // So on and so forth
    } elseif($filter == '') {
        //So on and so forth
    }
} else {}
```

Comment: You REALLY need to read about SQL injection attacks. You explicitly escape data that never goes anywhere near your query, then directly stuff user-provided data into the query, leaving yourself wide open to an injection attack.

Comment: I agree with Marc B on this however I fail to see what the PHP even has to do with your question.

Comment: all that is is an example code.  My real code sanitizes all user input

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript to get the selected option index/value and then process from there.

```
selectBox = document.getElementById("select_field");
currentIndex = selectBox.selectedIndex;
currentValue = selectBox[currentIndex].value;
//Continue processing as you need
```

Depending on your needs that will give you the index value of the option the user has currently selected and the contents of the "value" attribue.

On a side note, your code is suseptible to SQL injection attacks and you if this is a new project you should consider using the MySQLi library over the regular mysql_* set of functions.  They are no longer in support and I believe they have been deprecated as well.

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML like this:

```
<select name="select_menu" id="select_field">
    <option value="select_one">Please Select One</option>
    <option value="search_between_dates">Search Between Two Dates</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="date" id="dpd1" class="dpd1">
<input type="text" name="date2" id="dpd2" class="hidden">
<div id="select_feed"></div>
```

Then you can use some jquery to show the second input:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
  $('#select_field').change(function() {
    if ($('#select_field').val() == "search_between_dates") {
      $('#dpd2').show();
    }
  });
});
```

Note:  I didn't actually test the code, so there might be a subtle syntax error hidden there.